How to modify the return of the eigenvalues with eigen() in a NO decreasing order?
When the eigenvalues of a matrix are determined by eigen(), the eigenvalues are always returned in decreasing order.
I am wondering if with eigen() is possible to get the eigenvalues with a no specific order? Do you know if it is posible?
Example:
covMat <- var(cbind(A,B,C)) 
covMat 
           A          B         C
A 0.09687525 0.06327042 0.04580442
B 0.06327042 0.28298154 0.09056438
C 0.04580442 0.09056438 0.15467751

evals<-eigen(covMat)$values 
**[1] 0.43162433 0.10861830 0.06010923**

If it is not possible, is there any other R package where I can get the eigenvalues without any order?

I think you might need to clarify the context a little bit. Mathematically, eigenvalues have no order (i.e., they are an unordered set); it is a convention to order them from largest to smallest. Can you explain why the order of the eigenvalues matters to your subsequent calculations, and why the default largest-to-smallest ordering is not appropriate? (I've voted to close for "needs details or clarity" ... eigenvalues don't "come from a particular row/column" of the original matrix, except (possibly) as determined by a dominant element within the corresponding eigenvector ...

...just randomize the result?

I want to fix a dots cloud in an 90% ellipsoid and determine its lenghts (X = width, Y = height and Z = deep) in > 1000 samples individually. For each, I calculate the covariation matrix and I obtain 3 eigenvalues ordered from largest-to-smallest. After, I determine the lenghts of the ellipsoid using: 2sqrt(6.251eigenvuales). I obtain 3 numbers which are the ellipsoid lenghts = width, height and deep. The tricky thing: Since eigenvalues are in a decreasing order, I dont know which number correspond to each lenght since sometimes height can be larger than width and viceversa.

Apply a random permutation to the eigen output:
set.seed(123)
o <- sample(3, replace = FALSE); o
## [1] 3 1 2

e <- eigen(covMat)
e$vectors <- e$vectors[, o]
e$values <- e$values[o]

# check 
all.equal(unname(covMat), with(e, vectors %*% diag(values) %*% t(vectors)))
## [1] TRUE

Note
Input used
covMat <- matrix(c(0.09687525, 0.06327042, 0.04580442, 0.06327042, 0.28298154,
  0.09056438, 0.04580442, 0.09056438, 0.15467751), 3, 3, 
  dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))


Thank you very much for your quick answer. However, I would like to move a step forward: If I want to know from which column and row of my matrix are coming these eigenvalues, is it possible? In other words, can I determine my eigenvalues manually in R?

The ith eigenvalue, i.e. e$values[i], corresponds to the ith eigenvalue, i.e. the ith column of e$vectors.  In the answer we permutated both the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors to maintain the correspondence.

Thank you very much, again. But I think I am not transmitting well what I really want to get. I would like to control the order of the eigenvalues because the order matters for my after calculations. For this reason, I would like to know how can I code "manually" the equation iof determining the eigenvalues in R. Thank you :-)

The eigenvalues are the values  in e$values.
